# Can a honda iAVR generator safely run a computer?

Tags: generator, electronics

Honda advertises their iAVR generators as producing stable enough power to run a computer.  For example, see "applications" section at https://powerequipment.honda.com/generators/models/em6500.  However, THD, frequency tolerances, etc., aren't listed.

Can anybody here provide measurement-based reasons why or why not it's safe to power sensitive electronics with a honda iAVR generator?

Comment: Used generators to run computer fine, but put a simple load on the genny first so it was running stable then connected the computers...

Comment: It's always a good idea to put power filtering between any source and sensitive electronics - including computers, TVs,  stereo gear,... .   Even if the iAVR output is clean, "things" can happen on your house wiring or the grid feed into your house.

Comment: desktop or laptop?

Comment: @dandavis both, plus modem and network equipment

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, regarding power filtering, would you use a basic power conditioner, like a Furman SS6B, or something more advanced with a "clean power" generator?

Comment: I ask because things with an external AC/DC adapter, where the device takes in DC are typically more forgiving of dirty power than PC power supplies, which can get incremental damage to the MOVs and capacitors from such noise. The adapter is not immune to these either, but are easy to replace, and super cheap to "condition", just put some bulk capacitors in parallel with the DC output.

Answer (score 1):

The 'promise' of the iAVR generators is that they CAN power sensitive electronics like computers.  This is why they cost so much more. If you are concerned, I would put a spike filter and UPS in-between the source and the computer load; it wouldn't have to be a big one.  However, the computer has some natural filtering because it uses a an AC to DC power supply which already has filtering on both ends.